# When container div shrinks, google map disappears

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map in a div structure like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div id="divLeft" style="float:left;width:445px;height:100%;position:relative;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden">
    <div id="divRight" style="float:left;width:75%;position:relative">
         <input id="searchTextField" type="text" />
         <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `map-canvas` div is the actual map.

All of this works fine until I start resizing the browser window to make it smaller. Or even if the window starts out too small. The google map disappears completely. I have pinpointed the exact pixel width of the window when the map disappears. At 1335 pixel width or more, the map is there. At 1334 pixel width or less, it's gone. Notice the initial width of `divRight` (the div container of `map-canvas`) starts at 75%. This seems wrong and arbitrary, but it's all I can find that works. Any higher % and the map disappears from the very beginning. The window height can be anything and the map is fine. It is only the width that causes it to disappear. `divLeft` needs to be a fixed width of 445px, but I want `divRight` and `map-canvas` to fill 100% of the remaining window space.

This doesn't seem to solve the problem either:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Also I have tried dynamic resizing stunts with jquery, with no success:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#map-canvas").css("width", $("#divRight").width());
    $("#map-canvas").css("height", $("#divRight").height());
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Here is a simplified [web page showing the problem](http://zerogravpro.com/temp/_test.html). If you can't see a google map in the right-side div, just a bunch of whitespace, then your browser window is narrower than 1335 pixels in width. No idea what is special about that width.

Why does the google map want to disappear at a certain width, and how can I solve this?

Comment: No way to help without a demo that replicates problem

Comment: charlietfl: I added a link to a simplified web page showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that at the breakpoint the 75% width on right pane is greater than window width minus the 445px for left pane.

Thus the float is being pushed down and not visible due to body height being 100% and overflow hidden.

As a quick test, set left pane width to 25% and map will always show.

**Conclusion:**

Your resize code is addressing the wrong element. it should be checking `#divRight` width fits in window

Comment: Charlie, this sounds very promising, but what is your solution? The left pane has to remain fixed. I cannot change it to % or it will mess up a lot of fixed-width content in that div. How can I make divRight fill all available space and not disappear? Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: get overall window width, subtract the 445 and use that to set right element width. Map container is already set 100% so that should take care of it. Something like : `$('#divRight').width( $(window).width() -445))`